# Can I specify a connection string in the web.debug.config only?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config

I have a group of apps that inherit their connection string from a web.config in the root directory of IIS.  This means that I don't need to specify a connection string in the root directory of the app, but I do need to specify a connection string when debugging locally.

My question is, how can I set a connection string in web.debug.config that only is used when I'm debugging?

Answer (score 5):

You could specify the connectionstring in the normal web.config and then in the web.release.config add a transform that simply removes the connection string all together.

That way it should exist in the debug one but not in the web.release.config.

Of course this assumes you are using those configs with transforms and not doing a simple copy/paste of the code when you deploy

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) has a good example of this

> The following example shows how to select all the connection string
>   add elements in the development Web.config file. In the deployed
>   Web.config file, only the first connection string element is removed.

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="...">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add xdt:Transform="Remove" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

EDIT: I guess alternatively you could also create a transform in web.debug.config that adds it while in debugging, which might help to keep it out of the original web.config if you aren't appying transforms when deploying

Comment: This is the correct answer. Removing it from the local web.config via transform will allow it to inherit from the parent app just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your Debug connection string in Web.Config and replace the release connection string in Web.Release.Config using the locator as show below
`<connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Release Connections tring" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="XPath(configuration/connectionStrings)"/>
    </connectionStrings>`